# How do i INSERT/UPDATE a table varieble from a SELECT query from another table in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert/update a select query results to a table variable in sql-server stored procedure but for some reason only the first value is being updated

```
declare @student table(regdno int,semester_marks float null,temp float null);

insert into @student(regdno )
    select regdno
    from sem_marks
    where allocId =@allocid
    order by regdno asc;
```

AND

```
update @student
    set regdno = sem_marks.regdno
    from sem_marks
    where sem_marks .allocId =@allocid ;

declare @student table(regdno int,semester_marks float ,temp float );
```

declared the table variable

need to insert the values of regdno from another table sem_marks into  @student leaving columns semester_marks and temp blank currently which will be updated later on the the code

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server here (1 of which is completely unsupported, and another as close as). What version are you really using here?

Comment: Also, I would only expect your `UPDATE` statement to update one row. You have the clause `sem_marks.allocId =@allocid` in your `WHERE`. Considering that `@allocid` is a scalar value, and that `allocId` is likely unique, then that;s one row that needs updating. i think we're missing a few key pieces of information here.

Comment: We can't see your data, so how can we possibly guess why only the row you consider to be "the first value" is being updated?   Provide a script that fully reproduces the issue, and provide the results you are trying to get instead.  Your question is currently too unclear to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the fields. Start with reading the documentation if you get stuck...

Here's a perfect example for your insert:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#l-inserting-data-into-a-table-variable

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017